# How to pass argument to extension class constructor in JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, junit5, lombok

I have a problem to pass argument from test class to its extension class constructor.
Problem occurred during migration from JUnit4 to JUnit5. (For JUnit4 worked fine)
In JUnit4 test class looked like:

```
public class TestClass{
    @Rule
    @Autowired
    public SupportClass supportClass;
}
```

and Support class looked:

```
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class SupportClass implements TestRule {
        private final EntityManager entityManager;

        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                final Statistics statistics = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
                statistics.clear();

                base.evaluate();
            }
         };
        }
   }
```

In JUnit5 I am trying to do (test class):

```
@ExtendWith(SupportClass.class)
public class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    public SupportClass supportClass;
}
```

and Support class looks:

```
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class SupportClass implements AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {
        private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        final Statistics statistics = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        statistics.clear();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        final Statistics statistics = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        statistics.clear();

    }
   }
```

And when I am trying to execute test I get
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: .SupportClass.init()** exception. I know it is related to missing non args constructor. Unfortunately my SupportClass requires this argument to work. The question is how to pass this **entityManager** from test class to support as argument?

Comment: Have a look at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/RegisterExtension.html

Comment: Tried to put it over supportClass but it did not help. I have read this doc but I can not find any explanation how to exactly do that.

Comment: I have also tried with this tutorial [Guide JUnit5](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions), with parameter resolver interface, but still no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch. Not checked for compilation errors, no imports and probably not all details:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    @RegisterExtension
    SupportClass support;

    @Test
    void myTest() {...}
}

public class SupportClass implements AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    SupportClass(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        final Statistics statistics = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        statistics.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        final Statistics statistics = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        statistics.clear();

    }
}
```

I think `SupportClass` is not a good name, but that's a different story.